# problem on understanding locking and covering index

Tags: sql-server, blocking

As per my study, I found that a lot of people mention that the covering index would help to reduce the "key lookup" blocking. I was keen to test and understand it, but my testing did not show the expected result.

First I run the code below, I trying to update the table on the first transaction without commit and then on another session, I run a query to select the col2 and col3 from the tableA. According to the book, the second session will be block by the first session.

```
-- Create the table for testing
CREATE TABLE [TableA] 
(   
    [col1] INT,
    [col2] INT, 
    [col3] INT, 
    [col4] CHAR(100) DEFAULT('abc') NOT NULL
);
GO

DECLARE @int INT;
SET @int = 1;

-- Load data into the table
WHILE (@int <= 1000) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [TableA] 
        ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4])
    VALUES (@int*2, @int*2, @int*2, @int*2);
    SET @int = @int + 1;
END
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [cidx_TableA] 
ON [TableA] ([col1]);

-- Create a non-clustered index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_TableA_col2] 
ON [TableA] ([col2]);
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE [TableA] SET col3=999 WHERE Col2=4
--Rollback

--ON another session, I query this.
SELECT [col2],col3 FROM [TableA] 
WHERE [col2]=66
option (recompile)
```

The second session did using the key lookup to the Cluster index cidx_TableA and return the result, I expect it would no return any result because suppose it would lock by the update on first session. Why?

I am not yet create the covering index yet, because it did not make any blocking at all. So, did covering index really work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, but I will say probably the best decision would be to start looking at Read Committed Snapshot Isolation ([RCSI](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation)) this means you no longer require locks to read data (and as a bonus, you get meaningful results).

With the indexes as they currently are (assuming access via `idx_TableA_col2`), your update statement is going to lock

- The entries in the `idx_TableA_col2` index for the rows that get updated
- The rows in the table that get updated

Your select statement does not need to read any of those locked bits because you can seek to `WHERE [col2]=66` in the `idx_TableA_col2` index (avoiding the locked index entries) and use that to access just the rows in the table that match this condition (again, these rows are not locked).

The locking problem a covering index is trying to avoid is for where a row is updated but the query does not need to worry about this column. Your `update` statement is updating `col3`, which is involved in your select statement so your covering index on `([col2],[col3])` would get locked for these rows too as the update statement will need to update the entries in this index.

In order to demo the problem a covering index would solve, you would need to change the `update` statement to not be updating `col3` but have the `where` filter return the same rows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE [TableA] SET col4=999 WHERE Col2=4
--rollback

--ON another session
SELECT [col2],col3 FROM [TableA] 
WHERE [col2]=4
option (recompile)
```

But as I mentioned in the first paragraph, using RCSI will avoid this problem completely.